# Programmatically create a named vector with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a named vector where the names change according to the variable of a loop or a map. Something like this:

```
for (i in 1:5) { 
  named_vector <- c(
    str_c("variable_A_", i) = i,
    str_c("variable_B_", i) = i,
    str_c("variable_C_", i) = i
  ) 
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  named_vector <- c(
    str_c("variable_A_", i) ="
```

I know you can use the assign() function:

```
for (i in 1:5) { 
  named_vector <- c(
    assign(str_c("variable_A_", i), i),
    assign(str_c("variable_B_", i), i),
    assign(str_c("variable_C_", i), i)
  ) 
}
```

But if I do that I lose the name attribute, which I really need to do a `mutate(data, recode(column, !!!named_vector))` later on.

Thanks

Comment: Would you show what output vector you want ?

Comment: Create an unnamed vector, and add the names afterwards.  E.g. `named_vector <- c(i, i, i)`; names(named_vector) <- c(paste0("variable_A_", i). etc.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
named_vector <- setNames(rep(1:5, each = 3), 
                    paste0('variable_', 
                      outer(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 1:5, paste, sep = '_')))
named_vector

#variable_A_1 variable_B_1 variable_C_1 variable_A_2 variable_B_2 variable_C_2 
#           1            1            1            2            2            2
 
#variable_A_3 variable_B_3 variable_C_3 variable_A_4 variable_B_4 variable_C_4 
#           3            3            3            4            4            4
 
#variable_A_5 variable_B_5 variable_C_5 
#           5            5            5
```